# I got an Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am kind of new to React.
And I got this Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]).
And I am not sure how to fix this issue.
Can you guys take a look? Thanks!

Here's my code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

async function randomVerse() {
  const url = "https://labs.bible.org/api/?passage=random&type=json";
  const passage = await fetch(url);
  const passageJson = await passage.json();

  return passageJson;
}

const displayRandomVerse = async () => {
  let result = await randomVerse();
  let verse = "";
  verse += result[0].text;
  return verse;
};

const returnVerse = displayRandomVerse();

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      verse: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({verse: returnVerse});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Good Morning, XXX!</h1>
        <h3>Bible verse : {this.state.verse} </h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch and await in your componentDidMount method

```
async function randomVerse() {
      const url = "https://labs.bible.org/api/?passage=random&type=json";
      const passage = await fetch(url);
      const passageJson = await passage.json();
    
      return passageJson;
    }
    
    const displayRandomVerse = async () => {
      let result = await randomVerse();
      let verse = "";
      verse += result[0].text;
      return verse;
    };
    
    
    class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          verse: null
        };
      }
    
      async componentDidMount() {  //Notice changes in this section
        this.setState({verse: await displayRandomVerse()});
      };
    
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <h1>Good Morning, XXX!</h1>
            <h3>Bible verse : {this.state.verse} </h3>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: it is working here check it out https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-moc72 Did you add async before componentDidMount?

Comment: Nevermind! I forgot to add async before componentDidMount. Your suggestion worked!! Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set await in **const returnVerse = await displayRandomVerse();**. This should give you the value